# Docker run with "-v" create another shared directory

Tags: docker

I have a strange problem running a Docker container
It is working OK if I run:

```
docker run -it -v /home/drleo/pythonCourses:/home/pythonCurses /redpmorg/python-courses
```

But if I run container with publish option the Docker will create a new folder in my /home/drleo directory with the SAME name: pythonCourses, owned by root but obviously empty:

```
 docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -v /home/drleo/pythonCourses:/home/pythonCurses /redpmorg/python-courses

-rw-r--r--   1 drleo drleo   675 May  6  2016 .profile
drwxr-xr-x   2 drleo drleo  4096 May  6  2016 Public
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root   4096 Feb 16 13:08 pyhtonCourses
drwxrwxr-x   2 drleo drleo  4096 Feb 16 13:08 pythonCourses
-rwxrwxr-x   1 drleo drleo    71 Jan 20 22:35 reset-network
```

The question is why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a type somewhere. py**th**on != py**ht**on.

Double check your command history.

Comment: Ohh yes! Obviously! Thank you!